# how can I calculate $P(X_1\leq X_2\leq X_3)$

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are random sample of distribution with probability function
$P(X=k)=(1-\theta)\theta^k , k=0,1,2,... ,\theta \in (0,1)$ how can calculate $P(X_1\leq X_2\leq X_3)$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your $X_i$ are independent, the answer is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(k \leq X_2\leq X_3|X_1=k)P(X_1=k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-\theta)\theta^k\sum_{i=k}^\infty (1-\theta)\theta^i\sum_{j=i}^\infty (1-\theta)\theta^j.$$

The sums are fairly straightforward to evaluate. We have that:

$$\sum_{j=i}^\infty (1-\theta)\theta^j=1-(1-\theta^i)=\theta^i$$

and,

$$\sum_{i=k}^\infty (1-\theta)\theta^{2i}=(1-\theta)\frac{1-(1-\theta^{2k})}{1-\theta^2}.$$

Can you finish it from here? The correct answer should be:

$$\frac{1}{(\theta+1)(\theta^2+\theta+1)}.$$

Comment: You don't seem to have left any of the actual probability calculations for the OP, who has shown no effort to formulate or solve the problem. Also, congratulations to the OP for getting an upvote for posting a homework or test problem with zero intellectual content added.

Comment: My approach to broaching questions that might be potential homework problems is ... to wait a week or two before answering. It's a pity to close, because the problem may be of interest to others.